# How to set the temp directory for awmp in actix web with awmp::PartsConfig or how to use awmp::PartsConfig with acrix web?

Tags: rust, actix-web

app_data(web::Data::new(
awmp::PartsConfig.with_temp_dir("/home/o/blah/static/image"); // returns struct not
//value
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this syntax is wrong, my bad.
for the code to return a value, the correct code is:
...
app_data(awmp::PartsConfig::default().with_temp_dir("#directory_name")...